# Custom SQL functions in Django test database

Tags: python, django

I'm creating `unittest` tests for Django with PostgreSQL database. I'm trying to invoke a function which is in the project database, but the test fails because it doesn't find that function.

I think the reason is because the test database is created when the test is running, and it not load the functions in the original database.

My question is, ¿how could I include that function in the Django test database?

Answer (score 1):

Use [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) in a migration

```py
from django.db import migrations


CUSTOM_SQL_FUNCTION = """
create or replace function custom_sum(arr integer[])
returns int
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
    result integer;
begin
    select sum(a) into result
    from unnest(arr) a;
    return result;
end;
$$;
"""

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', 'prev_migration_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(CUSTOM_SQL_FUNCTION)
    ]
```

To create new migration file run

```sh
$ python manage.py makemigrations --name add_custom_function app_name --empty
```

where `app_name` is your Django app

Answer (score 0):

Manually create a migration, and run your sql files from there. Something along these lines:

```
from django.db import migrations, connection

# you can add more sql files here later on, bc these are just for testing
def run_raw_sql(apps, schema_editor):
    f = open('/home/edgle/web/plan/sql/get_plan_data.sql', 'r')
    sql = f.read()
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql)

    f = open('/home/edgle/web/plan/sql/role_recursion.sql', 'r')
    sql = f.read()
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql)

def reverse_run_raw_sql(apps, schema_editor):
    pass  # fake

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', 'previous_migration_name'),
        ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(run_raw_sql, reverse_run_raw_sql),
        ]
```

Comment: There is a migrations.RunSQL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#runsql